# How to make a type check to prove that an unknown object has all of the nested keys I need it to have

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make sure the object has all of the keys I expect it to have (`.result.items`), the only problem is I get the following error:

```
Property result does not exist on type 'object'
```

on:

```
typeof (object.result as Record<string, any>).items === "object"
```

I do not understand this error because it seems that I already proved that `object.result` does exist with my previous line and it should be of type object.

```js
let objectKeyCheck = (
  object: unknown
): object is { result: { items: object[] } } => {
  return (
    !!object &&
    typeof object === "object" &&
    !!(object as Record<string, any>).result &&
    typeof (object as Record<string, any>).result === "object" &&
    !!(object.result as Record<string, any>) &&
    typeof (object.result as Record<string, any>).items === "object"
  );
};
```

Comment: This isn't quite a [mre] because you're checking that `typeof object.result === "object"` without checking if it's not `null`, so you might dereference `null` at runtime.  Also, `wrestlersType` is not defined. That's not what you're asking about, so maybe you could clear it up?

Comment: When you write `(object.result as Record<string, any>)` you have "shielded" `object.result` from control flow analysis.  If you want behavior like this I'd refactor so you don't use type assertions on anything you're type guarding, like [maybe this](https://tsplay.dev/mM851N).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: It seems like that should work but I get the same error on line ```!!object.result &&```

Comment: I can't reproduce an error.  Are you using some old version of TypeScript, and if so, is your question dependent on using an old version?  Any thoughts about [edit]ing the question code to clear up the potential confusion I mentioned in my first comment?

Comment: I am not being rude here, but I have no idea what you want me to clear up; probably because I am dumb lol. My boss is set on using legacy so that is probably it. Thank you so much for your help! I didn't even know you could test for keys in objects.

Comment: You know that `typeof null` is `"object"`, right?  If I pass in `{result: null}` for `object` to your function as-written, it will throw an error, because `typeof object.result === "object"` so you will then go on to check `object.result.items`, which dereferences `null`.  You need to also check `!!object.result`.   Since you already checked `!!object` in addition to `typeof object === "object"` it seems you are aware of the need to check for `null`.  Your typing question has little to do with this, but it's distracting.  Could you fix it?  Or say the word and I'll fix it.

Comment: Just fix it please I am not sure I understand what you mean. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me :)

Comment: All right, I'll do this when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when you use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) on an expression, it "shields" the expression from any [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) which might normally happen.  For example:

```
function foo(x: string | number) {

  if (typeof x === "string") {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase()); // okay
  }

  if (typeof (x as string) === "string") {
    console.log(x.toUpperCase()); // error!
  }

}
```

In the first block we are performing a [`typeof` type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) on `x`, which allows us to narrow it from `string | number` to just `string`.  But in the second block we aren't guarding `x`, we're guarding `x as string`... which has no effect whatsoever on `x`.

Type assertions and narrowings don't really mix.

---

In order to fix this, I'd stay away from type assertions, and just use the support added in TypeScript 4.9 for [unlisted property narrowing using the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator):

```
let objectKeyCheck = (
    object: unknown
): object is { result: { items: object[] } } => {
    return (
        !!object &&
        typeof object === "object" &&
        "result" in object &&
        !!object.result &&
        typeof object.result === "object" &&
        "items" in object.result &&
        !!object.result.items &&
        typeof object.result.items === "object"
    );
};
```

Once we narrow `object` from `unknown` to `object`, then we check `"result" in object` and suddenly the compiler will treat `object.result` as a valid index, and the property type starts off as `unknown`. Then we can narrow `object.result` to type `object`, and do likewise with `object.result.items`.

Note that the above relies on a feature added in TypeScript 4.9.  If you're using an earlier version there are almost certainly other approaches which also fix the problem, but I'm not going to digress here with exploring them as they are already out of date and will become less useful over time.  The recommended thing to do is to upgrade TypeScript, and those who need code that targets a particular older version, might want to ask a new question with explicit requirements around language versioning.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBA9gRgViAxmA0iAngYQBZINYQC8EAFAFATTxJgBcEArgHZ5NQDuTZAlPbAsggBLAM4QA3hABOIEQ2B0JwsCAC2IvtWQBtALoQAvoaIA+CRWngGUpqQuUAhA-40IAMjf2IYdAAcQUABmVAKQhOEQAEQuyJHunpSODiQxkACGYgBKSFBSACYAPCJgUkJMAOYANBBpTOgm3AB0MnIK8V4+-kGkqTVZOflFJWVVNXUNzbLyYRHRWmBxHl5OKfOTren9iLmFxaUV1bX13O2J3n4Bwauh69N9ENnbg3sjh+NNQirqRLOpkRbcADcZAMwLIgWYyCEUFsgSgUBIAA96C8KhAAD4QJgMVQwEBSE7iMgWIRXTqXCCIn7ESKo8qRQlebZMERQUCNYBQcpIxpgKAAVV8-ikmAyIBI3CBEAA9NLoHg0ugLAZiZRSaRyd0kfc6SdwjS6QzzGdmaz2ZzuYjeQKhfjRSJxZLATK5fipLkHMriSriaBIKk0FhcIg8AAmIh2M6pejMVgcLi8EKuURKFrTeiST5qDRJnT6IxGQhmIlnGRgay2chnM5OXpLauJTXBXr6qJ-U4NqJphRxMq5yD1zu1tbdgcJTtN-u3NqtuahRbjhuRLPqXu2VLTsdeGvOEdTBSNFdiQcNycb0eHr5iWd-LxAkGAoA)

Comment: This is an excellent answer thank you very much for taking the time to help. I understand what you are saying about type assertions and I did not realize it shields narrowing... very useful information you are sharing here and I really appreciate it.